Present Perfect + After + Present Perfect vs. Past Perfect / What is the difference?

She's prepared roast beef with a hollandaise sauce, a crab salad, and bought some baklava for dessert. "Incredible," Richard says. She watches him eat, eating little herself. When they've finished, they spread a blanket out on the beach and lie back, watching the sunset. [...] "Tell me a story," Donna says suddenly, sitting up. She has said this to him before, usually after they've made love. He has come to know what sort of story she wants: something from his younger days, a tale of irresponsible weekend madness, some comedy of errors.

Virtually Everything by Allen G. S.
Could someone explain to me if instead of "they've made love" were "they'd made love" would there be any difference?
I've found similar examples in which the past perfect was used too, so I'd like to know if there is any particular reason behind that.
For example:

Well, sir, we did not want to marry Japs, we did not want our women to marry them, or our daughters. To the Japs, women are less than cattle, and what is happening now in the war proves this is so.' "' What is happening?' "' Why, sir, the Japs are now fighting with women, so that they can stay behind and be protected.' "' Women?' "' Oh, yes, sir. Japanese and Korean women, and, sadly, even some of our own. At first they were used only as whores, but lately we have begun to find women, after they had been killed by our fire, wearing uniforms and fighting as men.' "' And you believe the Japs forced them into battle?' I asked, appalled. "' Oh, yes, sir, thank you, sir.'

Here Stands A Man by Blaine and Brenton Yorgason
Here in the second example, it could also be "after they have been killed" too with no change in meaning as far as I can see.
I'd appreciate your help!

There isn't any difference. The Yorgason character could equally well have said after they have been killed.

The narrator has chosen to  tell the the story in the present tense(s):

She [ha]s prepared roast beef with a hollandaise sauce, a crab salad, and [has] bought some baklava for dessert. "Incredible," Richard says. She watches him eat, eating little herself. When they [ha]ve finished, they spread a blanket out on the beach and lie back, watching the sunset. [...] "Tell me a story," Donna says suddenly, sitting up. She has said this to him before, usually after they've made love. He has come to know what sort of story she wants: something from his younger days, a tale of irresponsible weekend madness, some comedy of errors.

The story contains an embedded "story", a reminiscence, and that reminiscence is also related using the present, the present-perfect:

She has said this to him before, usually after they've made love.

The reminiscence is about something that has recurred in their life, so it's not a distant memory; rather the character is thinking about their ongoing life together:  usually after they've made love.
Working our way outward from the reminiscence to the story proper, we can understand the present-tense narrative as a recounting of an ongoing life experience, not as a tale of lives that were lived in in the past.
Your past perfect example can be explained by normal sequence of events:

... lately we have begun to find women, after they had been killed by our fire, wearing uniforms and fighting as men.

The discoveries  occurred after the women had been killed in battle.

In fact, the author is hyper correct.

The narrator is 100% consistent in the use of the present tense. I find it a little unnatural to be so consistent.

When I think of the Mormons who at times come to our doors, it's sort of in keeping with that. A kind of clean-cut text.

To be fair, if the narrator was only 70% consistent with his tenses, we'd have an even higher workload explaining it all.

Would it be unnatural or had a different meaning if the author of the first excerpt had chosen "..., usually after they'd made love." and the author of the second excerpt had chosen "..., after they have been killed by our fire, ..."? Would you explain this to me?

"usually after they had made love" wouldn't be temporally appropriate following upon "she has said this to him before". The past perfect conflicts somewhat with usually.  Compare: "I have rushed to catch the train before, usually after I had overslept."  The past perfect portrays the event in relation to another past event, whereas usually talks about something that happened on multiple occasions.

There is no such conflict in the war example involving women fighters.  "We have begun  to find women, after they have been killed by our fire, wearing uniforms ..."  That presents the finding and the killing as things occuring together lately. after establishes the temporal relationship of the finding and the killing.  The past perfect is compatible with that  sequential (first killing then finding) relationship but is not required  in order to establish the sequence of events when after does it.

@TimR If we disposed of the usually, would than the past perfect work here: 1) "She has said this to him before, after they'd made love." 2) "I have rushed to catch the train before, after I had overslept."?

@MickeyQ If we omit usually and change they've made love to they'd made love, the meaning changes from something she has said to him occasionally to something she once said to him. Same with the train: this is the second time the speaker is rushing to catch the train, although this time not necessarily as a result of oversleeping.

@TimR Does it mean that this sentence isn't correct: "I've played golf several times before, after I'd finished my work first."? It sounds good to me! Should I use the present perfect for the second verb?

@MickeyQ This sentence is elliptical and consists of two independent clauses each with a different focus:  "I've played golf several times before -- [it was] after I'd finished my work first."  The second  clause is an afterthought, not an integrated subordinate clause. Two utterances in one, so to speak, OK in conversational English. If you wanted to make it a single sentence, main clause and subordinate, I'd suggest: "I've played golf  several times before, after finishing my work."  Even so the sentence is going in two different directions semantically.

@TimR ​"But, as Scott says, this is not a progressive kindergarten where everybody gets points for trying. You do work in public - and that includes the reviews that Scott and other critics write - and you open yourself to criticism. What alternative are you suggesting? (" If you can't say something nice... "?) Scott's example was about somebody reading the review before the fact; I have often used examples of people reading a review after they've already had their own experience with the movie." - A.O. Scott on criticism: THIS IS NOT A PROGRESSIVE KINDERGARTEN

@TimR "I remember riding my horse right through those fields, across the train tracks, and over to my grandma's house. Guess Kansas took its time getting civilized, right, Gary?"  Gary listened politely because he mowed the doctor's lawn and cut roses for the doctor's wife. "That's something, Dr. Kettler. I've never been on a horse myself." " Never? Well, all the better for your head. Can't tell you the number of people I've had come in here after they'd been kicked by a horse." -  Erika Williams: Done in by a Bad Leg

@TimR My last question: can we use the present perfect and the past perfect (bolded) interchangeably in these two examples or they convey different things?

In those two examples either the present perfect or the past perfect would do, the past perfect version reinforcing the sequence of events. Going back to your golf example: it did not seem to be about a sequence of events at all, even though it involves play after work was finished;  I struck me as saying, to paraphrase, "I've played golf a few times in my life, I'm not a total newb" ("several times before") and the second half about playing golf after work seemed unrelated --requiring further context. Why bring up work? Has a person asked you to play golf over the lunch hour?

The golf sentence struck me as somewhat incoherent, as I said, going in two directions.

@TimR Yes, the idea was that my colleagues asked me to play golf with them over the lunch break and my answer was the sentence above. I made a mistake not providing wider context. But, anyway, I got it now! Thanks a lot for your help!

"after they'd made love" could refer to a particular occurrence only whereas "after they've made love" only refers to what they generally do afterwards.

Timchessish, consider My grandchildren are about to be introduced to opera. After they’ve heard a particularly good performance, they will come to see what all the fuss is about.
